# In Swift, get syntax error in convenience initializer when creating an object

Tags: swift, class, initialization, convenience-methods

I know a little about how to use convenience initializer and designated initializer.Here is a sample class called ClassA

```
class ClassA {
    var number:Int

    convenience init(){
        self.init(newNumber: 10)
    }

    init(newNumber: Int) {
        self.number = newNumber;
    }
}
```

This class works well but I got some trouble when implementing another class called Base. Here is the code:

```
class Base {
    var classObject:ClassA

    init(object: ClassA) {
        self.classObject = object
    }

    convenience init(){
        self.init(object: ClassA.init())
    }
}
```

In the convenience initializer of class Base, I call the convenience initializer of ClassA and take it as the argument of the designated initializer of Base.

However, I get two syntax errors.

1. Expected member name or constructor call after type name.
2. () is not convertible to Class A.

If I use

```
self.init(object: ClassA.init(newNumber: 10))
```

instead of

```
self.init(object: ClassA.init())
```

Then the first error disappears. It seems that the convenience initializer of ClassA is not recognized.

Comment: Your code compiles perfectly for me. Perhaps you've hit a bug in an earlier version of Swift? Update to Swift 2.0 and try again. Voting to close as irreproducible.

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.4.  Should I update it to 7.0?

Comment: @matt It does not compile correctly.  `ClassA.init()` returns void. You should use `ClassA()`

Comment: It *is* reproducible with Xcode 6.4.

Comment: @MartinR If it's a bug in Xcode 6.4 and it's fixed in Xcode 7, then it's a fixed bug. — However, @Roger is also right: use of explicit `init()` should be confined to things like `self.init()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `self.init(object: ClassA())`

Comment: I don't know who has down voted for what reason. You should leave a message at least?

Comment: This is ok. I have tried to do so before. But why doesn't my code work? There is no error if I use `var object = ClassA.init()` outside the definition of class Bae

Comment: @sevenkplus As I said in the comment. `ClassA.init()` returns `void` instead of an instance of the object. You should use ClassA(). Maybe you should be using that in the Objective-C class which has a class method named `init`

Comment: In your code `ClassA.init()` returns `Void`, the () in you error which is not convertible to `Class A`. So you can use this outside. And if you print it out `println(object)`, you will see the magic

Comment: This can explain why I got an error.But as you said, I used both ways to create an object outside and print it out. Both of the output is in the format of PROJECT_NAME.CLASS_NAME.

Comment: @sevenkplus seems it's a bug

Comment: So, in conclusion, I should always user ClassName() instead of ClassName.init() to create an instance of a class unless it's in the  convenience initializer.Right?